# Foundation 5 .end

Tags: zurb-foundation

Zurb Foundation 3 and 4 had the .end class for the last child in a grid if you did not want it to float right. Since updating to Foundation 5 all our .end classes seems to have stopped working.

I've looked in the Foundation Documentation but I can't find any pointers. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest version there is now;

```
.end {
  float: right !important; }
```

which is pushing it over. Swapping this out for .left seems to fix it.
HTH

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an ill-conceived bi-directional layout addition to Foundation 5 that will be fixed when Foundation 5.0.4 is released.

This [github issue](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/4215) documents the problem.

Comment: Thanks Philip, actually that's my posted issue on GitHub. If you are experiencing the same problem - stop using the .end -class alltogether and try the .left -class. Does the same thing (there is also a .right class for floating stuff to the right).

Comment: Ah, good work! I opted to override `.end` with a `float:left`, hopefully I can remove the override once 5.0.4 is released if `.end` is restored to its original functionality.